# Picklist bound to multiple fields

Tags: apex, picklist

I have a custom picklist (lets call it hours), that is bound to multiple fields in an object (we'll call this WorkActivity).

In object (WorkActivity) I have fields; TravelTime, BreakTime, OtherActivityTime that use this picklist.

In controller I'm getting picklist values by referencing TravelTime field (code below):

```
public List<SelectOption> getHours() {
    List<SelectOption> hours = new List<SelectOption>();
    hours.add(new SelectOption('', '-- Total Hours --'));

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult totalHours = WorkActivity__c.TravelTime__c.getDescribe();

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> hr = totalHours.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry i : hr) {
        hours.add(new SelectOption(i.getLabel(), i.getValue()));  
    }
    return hours;
}
```

My question is; is it better to instantiate 3 lists for each field this picklist is bound to?

It seems redundant doing that, but at the same time it feels a bit uncomfortable referencing TravelTime and using the list on BreakTime and OtherActivityTime.

(On a sidenote; looked up referencing the picklist directly, but it seems like I can only do this from the object...)

**EDIT (Additional code):**

Controller:

```
public String commHrSelected { get; set; }
public String mealHrSelected { get; set; }
public String othrHrSelected { get; set; }

public List<SelectOption> getCommuteHours() {
    List<SelectOption> hours = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult totalHours = Activity__c.CommutingTimeHours__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> hr = totalHours.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry i : hr) {
        hours.add(new SelectOption(i.getLabel(), i.getValue()));   
    }
    return hours;
}

public List<SelectOption> getMealHours() {
    List<SelectOption> hours = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult totalHours = Activity__c.MealTimeHours__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> hr = totalHours.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry i : hr) {
        hours.add(new SelectOption(i.getLabel(), i.getValue()));   
    }
    return hours;
}

public List<SelectOption> getOtherHours() {
    List<SelectOption> hours = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult totalHours = Activity__c.OtherActivityHours__c.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> hr = totalHours.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry i : hr) {
        hours.add(new SelectOption(i.getLabel(), i.getValue()));   
    }
    return hours;
}
```

VisualForce:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!commHrSelected}" size="1" styleClass="lists-small">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!commuteHours}" />
</apex:selectList>

<apex:selectList value="{!mealHrSelected}" size="1" styleClass="lists-small">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!mealHours}" />
</apex:selectList>

<apex:selectList value="{!othrHrSelected}" size="1" styleClass="lists-small">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!otherHours}" />
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: You only need one select options ( say getHours) list but you need 3 separate variables to store the picked value like you currently have. You can't use the hours field directly as all references to it on the page will be to the same field if that makes sense

Comment: I think I get that, SelectOptions value can all use "getHours" list, but SelectList value should have separate setter variable. Correct?

Comment: yes. A quick mock up should confirm for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have TravelTime, BreakTime, OtherActivityTime fields which will refer same picklist values, so content can be same. But you need to instantiate 3 variables for the list.

Otherwise, selection of TravelTime pickvalue may interfere the reference for BreakTime and OtherActivityTime

**Update**

Based on your code, take this approach to make it reusable code which is much cleaner

```
public String commHrSelected { get; set; }
public String mealHrSelected { get; set; }
public String othrHrSelected { get; set; }

public List<SelectOption> getCommuteHours() {
    return createPicklistValues (Activity__c.CommutingTimeHours__c.getDescribe());
}

public List<SelectOption> getMealHours() {
    return createPicklistValues (Activity__c.MealTimeHours__c.getDescribe());
}

public List<SelectOption> getOtherHours() {
    return createPicklistValues (Activity__c.OtherActivityHours__c.getDescribe());
}


public List<SelectOption> createPicklistValues(Schema.DescribeFieldResult fr)
{
    List<SelectOption> lstSelectOption = new List<SelectOption>();

    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> hr = fr.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry i : hr) {
        lstSelectOption.add(new SelectOption(i.getLabel(), i.getValue()));   
    }
    return lstSelectOption; 
}
```

Comment: I was afraid of that... lol

Comment: Could you explain a little further about why this is the case?
Seems easier to just reference the picklist directly then for each field.

Comment: are you creating single variable and trying to reference 3 fields? If yes then it will be the issue

Comment: I was using one picklist for 3 dropdowns, different setters per field.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Added the code, it's very basic coding. I'm just wondering why it has to be so redundant and verbose, considering they're all referencing the same picklist.

Comment: Updated my answer with code, just an approach I have given

Comment: Looks much cleaner, let me try that and get back to you.